# Vb.net access an item in a list inside a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I created a Dictionary in VB.net to contained a list

```
 Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Double))
```

Then on a loop I add a Key and Items to the list.

```
dic.Add("Key1", New List(Of Double))
```

do some stuff and add the items to the list of the key

```
Dic("Key1").Add(1.1078)
Dic("Key1").Add(12.232)
Dic("Key1").Add(33.365)
```

etc

How Do I access the value of the list using a Key

```
Console.writeline(Dic.Item("Key1")(1))
```

I was trying to print index 1 of the list associated with Key1
but I get a crash

Thanks
Kiko

Comment: define "crash" is there a message associated with it?

Comment: Yes but if I do Console.Writeline(Dic.Item("Key1")) I get the result "System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.double] What does that mean

Comment: the crash msg is System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException

Comment: the code looks correct - `Console.writeline(Dic.Item("Key1")(1))` should print 12.232

Comment: `dic` may be declared in a different scope.  what does `Console.WriteLine(dic("Key1").Count)` do/print?

Comment: Ops, stupid got it!! I had the (0) at the wrong place, what why it couldn't find the key!! Sorry about this, I posted the question right and had it wrong on the code!! My Bad

Answer (score 0):

You have found the answer meanwhile. I would just like to add that a safer method would be to use `TryGetValue`:

```
Dim list As List(Of Double)
If dic.TryGetValue("Key1", list) Then
    Console.WriteLine(list(0))
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Key1 not found!")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple.

```
dic("key1").item(1)
```